# access_log process in hive

Tags: regex, logging, hadoop, hive

i have `access_logs` around `500MB`,i am giving **sample** as

```
10.223.157.186 - - [15/Jul/2009:14:58:59 -0700] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 403 15779
10.223.157.186 - - [15/Jul/2009:14:58:59 -0700] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 404 5397
10.216.113.172 - - [29/Apr/2010:07:19:48 -0700] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 68831
```

how can i **extract month** from **timestamp**?

**Expected output :**

```
year   month    day    event occurrence

2009   jul      15     GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1

2009   apr      29     GET / HTTP/1.1
```

i **tried** this

```
add jar /usr/lib/hive/lib/hive-contrib-0.7.1-cdh3u2.jar;

create table log(ip string, gt string, gt1 string, timestamp string, id1 string, s1 string, s2 string) row format serde 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.contrib.serde2.RegexSerDe'                          
with serdeproperties('input.regex'= '^(\\S+) (\\S+) (\\S+) \\[([[\\w/]+:(\\d{2}:\\d{2}):\\d{2}\\s[+\\-]\\d{4}:/]+\\s[+\\-]\\d{4})\\] "(.+?)" (\\S+) (\\S+)')location '/path';
```

If i understand correctly string functions will not work in this situation.i am new to `regex` & `hive`.

help me..thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with hadoop/hive, but as far as regexes go, if I were using ruby:

```
log_file = %Q[
  10.223.157.186 - - [15/Jul/2009:14:58:59 -0700] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 403 15779
  10.223.157.186 - - [15/Jul/2009:14:58:59 -0700] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 404 5397
  10.216.113.172 - - [29/Apr/2010:07:19:48 -0700] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 68831
]

converted_lines = log_file.split("\n").map do |line|
  regex = /^.*? - - \[(\d+)\/(\w+)\/(\d{4}).*?\] (.*)/
  matches = regex.match(line)
  output = [
    [:year, matches[3]],
    [:month, matches[2]],
    [:day, matches[1]],
    [:event_occurrence, matches[4]],
  ]
end
```

Hope that helps.